# How to get the correct data in Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have JSON model,

```
{
  "legends": {
    "all": {
      "Revenant": {
        "ImgAssets": {
          "icon": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/icons\/revenant.png",
          "banner": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/banners\/revenant.jpg"
        }
      },
      "Crypto": {
        "ImgAssets": {
          "icon": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/icons\/crypto.png",
          "banner": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/banners\/crypto.jpg"
        }
      },
      "Horizon": {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Season 7 wins",
            "value": 1,
            "key": "wins_season_7",
            "rank": {
              "rankPos": 62637,
              "topPercent": 69.39
            },
            "rankPlatformSpecific": {
              "rankPos": 56257,
              "topPercent": 68.58
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Special event kills",
            "value": 101,
            "key": "specialEvent_kills",
            "rank": {
              "rankPos": 101058,
              "topPercent": 65.11
            },
            "rankPlatformSpecific": {
              "rankPos": 68184,
              "topPercent": 61.62
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Special event damage",
            "value": 47004,
            "key": "specialEvent_damage",
            "rank": {
              "rankPos": 96259,
              "topPercent": 58.78
            },
            "rankPlatformSpecific": {
              "rankPos": 66031,
              "topPercent": 55.63
            }
          }
        ],
        "ImgAssets": {
          "icon": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/icons\/horizon.png",
          "banner": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/banners\/horizon.jpg"
        }
      },
      "Wraith": {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Kills",
            "value": 1356,
            "key": "kills",
            "rank": {
              "rankPos": 162196,
              "topPercent": 12.69
            },
            "rankPlatformSpecific": {
              "rankPos": 121593,
              "topPercent": 10.29
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Season 7 kills",
            "value": 233,
            "key": "kills_season_7",
            "rank": {
              "rankPos": 17859,
              "topPercent": 38.15
            },
            "rankPlatformSpecific": {
              "rankPos": 15854,
              "topPercent": 36.65
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Season 7 wins",
            "value": 13,
            "key": "wins_season_7",
            "rank": {
              "rankPos": 11891,
              "topPercent": 13.97
            },
            "rankPlatformSpecific": {
              "rankPos": 10926,
              "topPercent": 13.47
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Special event kills",
            "value": 1377,
            "key": "specialEvent_kills",
            "rank": {
              "rankPos": "NOT_CALCULATED_YET",
              "topPercent": "NOT_CALCULATED_YET"
            },
            "rankPlatformSpecific": {
              "rankPos": "NOT_CALCULATED_YET",
              "topPercent": "NOT_CALCULATED_YET"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Special event damage",
            "value": 656195,
            "key": "specialEvent_damage",
            "rank": {
              "rankPos": "NOT_CALCULATED_YET",
              "topPercent": "NOT_CALCULATED_YET"
            },
            "rankPlatformSpecific": {
              "rankPos": "NOT_CALCULATED_YET",
              "topPercent": "NOT_CALCULATED_YET"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Special event wins",
            "value": 68,
            "key": "specialEvent_wins",
            "rank": {
              "rankPos": "NOT_CALCULATED_YET",
              "topPercent": "NOT_CALCULATED_YET"
            },
            "rankPlatformSpecific": {
              "rankPos": "NOT_CALCULATED_YET",
              "topPercent": "NOT_CALCULATED_YET"
            }
          }
        ],
        "ImgAssets": {
          "icon": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/icons\/wraith.png",
          "banner": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/banners\/wraith.jpg"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I make a data class:

```
data class TestHero (@SerializedName("global") val global: PlayerInf,
                     @SerializedName("legends")val legends: AllLegends)

data class  PlayerInf (val name: String, val uid: Long, val avatar: String, val platform: String,
val  level: Int, val toNextLevelPercent: Int, val internalUpdateCount: Int, val bans: BanInf, val rank: RankInf)

data class BanInf (val isActive: Boolean, val remainingSeconds: Int)

data class RankInf (val rankScore: Int, val rankName: String, val rankDiv: Int, val rankImg: String)


data class AllLegends (@SerializedName("all") val all : Revenant, @SerializedName("all")val all2: Horizon)

data class Revenant (val ImgAssets: String)
data class Horizon (val data : ArrayList<Rang0>, val ImgAssets: String)

class Legends(){
    data class Revenant (val ImgAssets: String)
    data class Horizon (val data : ArrayList<Rang0>, val ImgAssets: String)
}

data class Rang (val t0 : Rang0)
data class Rang0 (val name: String, val value: Int, val key: String)
```

But I get the error:

> Unable to create converter for class

Having looked for answers to stackoverflow, I realized that you can not double serialize a class object. But how do you get the data then?
I tried to do it separately, but it turned out to get the data of only 1 object
example:
`data class AllLegends (@SerializedName("all") val all : Revenant)`
help me figure it out please

Comment: Check this to understand how to parse nested objects. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55067977/9636037

Comment: @Abhimanyu Yes, I understand that. But I get in the object **all** there are nested objects Revenant Horizon Wraith and they are all ordered not as an array. That's why I don't understand how to get the necessary data from the object **all** . I hope I wrote correctly what I want to receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is a map of defined objects, but every legend is undefined

```
data class Legends(
    val all: Map<String, LegendWrapper> = emptyMap()
)
```

```
data class LegendWrapper(
    val data: Lis<PlayerPerformance>? = emptyList(),
    val ImgAssets: ImgAssets? = null

)
```

So you can define `PlayerPerformance` and `ImgAssets` on a class but can't define each "legend" because the keys for each are not static, that is why the map.

And in `LegendWrapper` you have to define `data` and `ImgAssets` as nullables because some "legends" doesn't have them.

This way inside of `Legends` you don't need to have `Ravenant, Crypto, Horizon...` and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot this works. Now I figure out how to access the map key

Comment: `all.values` or `all.forEach{ (key, value) -> } check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47204146/how-to-iterate-over-hashmap-in-kotlin and wlecome